# wordpress posts,categories,tags,users export/import

Tags: wordpress

I have already installed and worked template which has gone through many changes as per client need. But now am in big problem like integrating it with existing data. He already have more than 1400 posts with 400+ tags,80+ categories ,12 pages(also now i have added many pages). So now i have to import all the existing data into new wordpress(3.1). Is there any tool or extension to do this. Or please advice how should i handle this? I tried using wordpress importer which did part of the posts but then breaking down since it is too large. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your import stops halfway through an article, chances are that PHP reached its max_execution_time. You can change this value in your php.ini file, or break your import file in half, and resume from the article that was last imported successfully.